# Two empty options show up at start (select tag in html)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select

I have the below html code and when i see the UI, i see 2 empty dropdown items along with 10days, 30 days, 90 days option at the dropdown. Once i select either of the '10 days, 30 days, 90 days' option, then i see only 1 empty dropdown. Why am i seeing 2 empty dropdown option items. Here is the code.

```
<select ng-model="days">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="10D">10 days</option>
        <option value="30D">30 days</option>
        <option value="90D">90 days</option>
</select>
```

now, instead of above code, i use below code.

```
<select ng-model="days">
        <option value="10D">10 days</option>
        <option value="30D">30 days</option>
        <option value="90D">90 days</option>
</select>
```

here, i will see only 1 empty option tag. Upon selection of either '10 days, 30 days ,90 days', i donot see any empty option tag. i need an empty option tag here so that i cant revert back to no selection.

Can someone please suggest.

Comment: Tested on JSFiddle and it only shows one blank space in the first code, and no white spaces in your second code https://jsfiddle.net/zsrj4rgq/ Are you using other libraries and frameworks that could be affecting your select element?

Comment: Are you sure that one of the empty items isn't just the currently-selected value?